# is "function Pointer" in c++ similar in behavior with "delegate" in c#?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a small question.

is `function Pointer` in C++ similar in behavior with `delegate` in C# ?

Comment: What similarities and differences have you come across in your research?

Comment: From [MSDN: Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) `"Delegates are like C++ function pointers but are type safe."`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, Do you know exactly what they mean by function pointers being type-unsafe? Perhaps my brain's not on full power, but I can't see what they're referring to.

Comment: @chris: I still learn c++, and when I seen `function Pointer`, I remembered what I know in C# and especially delegate .

Comment: @chris I've never fully understood what they mean by that either. Many times I've relied on the static type safety of C function pointers. Like any other function, the parameter types must match, and even if you're passing a function pointer as a parameter, the entire signature must match. (Use a `typedef`!)

Comment: I've got some information about delegate in c# see. C# delegates are similar to pointers to functions, in C or C++. A delegate is a reference type variable that holds the reference to a method. The reference can be changed at runtime. is that right [the source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm) ?

Comment: @LionKing I think that describes it better and more succintly than the MSDN article.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're similar.

But function pointer in C++ cannot point to an instance method of class, while delegate in C# can.

Comment: Pedantically, function pointers cannot, but member function pointers can.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Well, a member function pointer has a different signature from a non-member function pointer.

Comment: Fair enough, I rescind my downvote. But since it is *possible* in C++ (albeit with a different name), I felt this was inappropriate for a question comparing the capabilities of C# to C++.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, That was more along my train of thought.

Comment: For the sake of reference, just want to add this great reference: [Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html).

Answer (score 1):

A .NET delegate can have state -- i.e. you can create a delegate to an object's instance method and have `this` be saved inside the delegate:

```
Foo f;
BarDelegate d = f.Bar;
d(); // stores f as 'this' pointer.
```

Function pointers have identical usage to delegates when they point to a non-member function. One could say they're actually better than delegates for this, because they're lighter weight (no allocations needed).

However, function pointers have no state. This makes them much different when using them with member functions -- `this` needs to be passed in as you call the function pointer:

```
Foo f;
BarPtr p = &Foo::Bar;
(f.*p)(); // need to pass in 'this' pointer. ugly call syntax!
```

In C++ we also have "functors" -- objects which can have state and you can call like a function. This is the most used replacement for delegates when calling templated functions. But a functor is just a type concept, not an actual type:

```
struct BarFunctor
{
    void operator()();
};

BarFunctor f;
f(); // not even a pointer, it's a full object and you're calling it.
```

A more apt comparison for exact duplication of a .NET delegate's functionality might be C++'s `std::function`, which is a functor which can wrap any other functor with a specific call signature. However, `std::function` isn't used a whole lot because like delegates they've got some overhead and templates often make such a heavyweight object unneeded:

```
Foo f;
std::function<void()> func = [&] { f.Bar(); }; // the lambda object (a
func();                                        // functor) capturing a
                                               // reference to f is
                                               // stored into func (also
                                               // a functor).
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes, but delegates are much richer.  A function pointer is just a pointer to the memory where a function resides.  A delegate is a class that wraps a function pointer along with other information.

Because basically everything in C# is a class, delegates can point to methods on a class.  In C++ this is a real pain because C++ functions use a special calling convention to call class methods, and the function pointer itself doesn't store a pointer to an object (you have to maintain that separately).

Delegates can also be chained together and have more type flexibility than C++ function pointers.  See [Covariance and Contravariance in Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: What is this "other information" that it wraps up?  I'm assuming a reference to the containing object, for one.

Comment: Ahh sorry... Yes, I don't have C# lingo down.  Reference to the `delegate` class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx -- I guess it's just `Method` and `Target` and some internal chaining list, but it always seemed like more to me because of the ability to extract runtime type information from those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, C#'s delegate is a class type which handles a function pointer. And a function pointer is just a 32bit or 64bit unsigned integer which points to the specific location in memory that the function in question resides. In C++ you just have a raw, unmanaged function pointer.